# amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master' on Raspbian 12 lite when running from systemctl service

Tags: raspbian, alsamixer

On my Raspbian 12 Lite box I can run:

```
amixer set Master 100%
```

to successfully change the master volume. But if I put it into a systemctl configuration in order to set volume at boot:

```
  [Unit]
  Description=Volume

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/amixer set Master 100%
  Restart=no
  User=fritz

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

it doesn't work, as journalctl gives:

```
Mar 28 23:02:56 raspberrypi amixer[109294]: amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
Mar 28 23:02:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: volume.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 28 23:02:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: volume.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As you can see, I specified the same user that I tried from terminal. Adding `Group=audio` doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As often happens, the solution came just minutes after I posted the question.

Fixed by adding under the `[Service]` section

```
  Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/7000"
```

where `7000` is the uid of the user.